# Does drive connected to SVN server require authorization?

Tags: svn, authorization, visualsvn-server, visualsvn, svn-server

I use VisualSVN as svnserver which manages the repository stored in X: drive. Not everyone has access to X: drive, but i want to give some of them access to repository. Do they need to have access to X: drive or passing authorization of visualsvn is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user account under which VisualSVN Server is running must have access to the location. Your other users **should not** have write permission there; you risk repository data loss/corruption if you do. All access, authorization & authentication to the repository should be managed through the Subversion server, not file/share/drive permissions.

Do not depend upon mapped drives for Windows services. If you must use a network share/path, use the UNC path. Drive letters are only usable for interactive user sessions.

If at all possible, keep your repository on a drive that is local to your Subversion server process, not a network share. More recent versions have mitigated the risks, but it's still recommended that you be on a local path.

Comment: server will have access to the drive, my question is do users connecting to server need to have access to drive? If I give them access to the drive, there is no point of authorization through server. Because they can simply go through drive and read or write what they want.

Comment: I believe I answered that in the first paragraph.

Comment: oh sorry i just misunderstood. Does that mean they will have read access through the drive but not write access or they will not have access at all?

Comment: There's no reason to give them any access at all at the filesystem level. **All** access should be through the SVN server itself, and the user account under which that service runs should be the only one that has access to the repository at the filesystem level.